# Calculate dunn index for Kernel Kmeans in r

Tags: r

I ran kmeans on my data using:

```
spherical_Data <- kmeans(myData,4)
```

Now to calculate dunn index I used:

```
spherical_Data <- kmeans(myData,4)
Dist <- dist(myData,method="euclidean")
dunn(Dist, spherical_Data$cluster)
```

Here the second argument to Dunn function is a vector that contains cluster memberships of all points in myData.

Now I ran kernalized kmeans as follows:

```
kernel_Kmeans <- kkmeans(myData, centers=4, kernel = "rbfdot", kpar = "automatic")
```

kernel_Kmeans gives me the following output:

```
Spectral Clustering object of class "specc" 

 Cluster memberships: 

3 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 1 4 3 1 2 1 3 3 4 2 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 4 1 2 3 3 2 3 4 2 2 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 1 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 3 1 2 3 2 4 3 1 2 3 2 4 2 3 2 1 3 3 4 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 4 2 3 2 4 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 1 4 1 1 3 3 2 4 3 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 3 4 2 1 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  7.63469658003494 

Centers:  
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.03108416 -0.2142212
[2,] -0.63034038 -0.6909727
[3,]  0.69360916  0.3623118
[4,] -0.95418284  0.1941879

Cluster size:  
[1] 287 209 389 115

Within-cluster sum of squares:  
[1] 286.34824  27.35574 188.54685 158.99104
```

To calculate Dunn index I need the first output i.e the vector containing the cluster membership of all points (marked under Cluster memberships).

```
dunn(Dist, kernel_Kmeans$cluster) does not work.
```

Can anybody tell me how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach to extract the cluster information from an object returned by `kkmeans`.

An example:

```
library(kernlab)
data(iris)
sc <- kkmeans(as.matrix(iris[,-5]), centers=3)
```

The output (`sc`):

```
Spectral Clustering object of class "specc" 

 Cluster memberships: 

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  0.957009094923757 

Centers:  
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 5.006000 3.428000 1.462000 0.246000
[2,] 6.554286 2.974286 5.300000 1.865714
[3,] 5.580000 2.633333 3.986667 1.233333

Cluster size:  
[1] 50 70 30

Within-cluster sum of squares:  
[1] 1313.240 2004.637  625.704
```

You can use `@.Data` to extract the information:

```
sc@.Data
#   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  [39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2
#  [77] 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# [115] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! Since I am a beginner to R can you tell me which other places is @.Data applicable. R seems to have a lot of such hidden variables. Is there any resource (tutorial) that points to such variables?

Comment: @Sudatta If you want to find out the structure of an object, you can use the function `str`. In this example: `str(sc)`.